# get kernel source code

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, source

I need a specific kernel version to compile it with some additional modules.

When I typing:

```
uname -r
```

I get

```
3.8.0-29-generic
```

I need this one.

```
 uname -a
 Linux "..." 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 16:19:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Where can I find this version? Here https://www.kernel.org/ seems that there isn't..

Comment: Sometimes it is enough to install the kernel headers with `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use `apt` to get the source, 
check that the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains a line starting with

```
deb-src
```

and then use the command:

```
apt-get update
#if you want to download the source into the current directory use:
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
#if you want the source to be installed in the system directory use:
apt-get install linux-source-$(uname -r)
```

It will download the source in the folder:

```
/usr/src or /usr/sources
```

Comment: The answer is not fully correct - it mixes two things. `apt-get source` downloads the package source files into the current directory. `/usr/src` is only filled if you are installing the source package with `apt-get install linux-source-$(uname -r)`.

Comment: @jofel thank you for the precision, I corrected my answer